# Probability of 4 disjoint randomly selected segments

Tags: probability

Select 4 random real numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ from $[0, 9]$. What is the probability that the 4 segments $[x_1,x_1+1],[x_2,x_2+1],[x_3,x_3+1],[x_4,x_4+1]$ are disjoint?

I have considered using linear programming. However in this question there are four dimensions and I think it is not the best way. I have no clue on how to solve this problem so can someone help?

Sorry for not putting any further information/attempts - as I don't have any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that if we select four values, each drawn uniformly and independently from $[0, 6]$, and call these $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ with $y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < y_4$, then there is a bijection

$$
x_1 = y_1 \\
x_2 = y_2+1 \\
x_3 = y_3+2 \\
x_4 = y_4+3
$$

that provides all satisfactory combinations and only those combinations.  Thus the desired probability is $\frac{6^4}{9^4} = \frac{2^4}{3^4} = 16/81 \approx 0.19753$.

ETA: Python code to simulate the question, just in case I've misunderstood it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

random.seed()

n = 1000000
t = 0
for i in range(n):
    x1 = random.random()*9
    x2 = random.random()*9
    x3 = random.random()*9
    x4 = random.random()*9
    if abs(x1-x2) > 1 and abs(x1-x3) > 1 and abs(x1-x4) > 1 \
    and abs(x2-x3) > 1 and abs(x2-x4) > 1 and abs(x3-x4) > 1:
        t += 1
print(float(t)/n)
```

---

Here's a breakdown of the two-dimensional analogue of this problem.  Suppose you choose two numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the interval $[0, 9]$, and you want the probability that the intervals $[x_1, x_1+1]$ and $[x_2, x_2+1]$ are disjoint.  That's the same as requiring that $|x_1-x_2| > 1$.

We can represent this situation graphically on the Cartesian plane:

[image]

The red triangles represent the portion of the $9$-by-$9$ space over which the condition is met.  Since the area of that $9$-by-$9$ square is $9^2 = 81$, and the combined area of the triangles is $64$, the desired probability is $64/81$.

Analogous to my answer above, we can alternatively generate the answer by choosing two numbers $y_1$ and $y_2$ from the square $[0, 8] \times [0, 8]$, and then adding $1$ to whichever one is larger.  This forces the two numbers to be separated by at least $1$.  Conversely, given any two numbers that satisfy the conditions, we can get a point in the $8$-by-$8$ square by subtracting $1$ from the larger number (without changing which number is larger).

Graphically, this represents splitting the $8$-by-$8$ square into two triangles and sliding the upper-left one up by one unit, and sliding the lower-right one right by one unit:

[image]

Something similar happens in higher dimensions, except that there are different numbers of identical parts being slid together to make a square/cube/hypercube.  In two dimensions, there are $2$ triangles that come together to make an $8$-by-$8$ square, because there are $2! = 2$ different ways to order two variables.  In three dimensions, there are $6$ pyramids that come together to make a $7$-by-$7$-by-$7$ cube, because there are $3! = 6$ different ways to order three variables.  In four dimensions, there are $24$ hyper-pyramids that come together to make a $6$-by-$6$-by-$6$-by-$6$ hypercube, because there are $4! = 24$ different ways to order four variables.  And so on.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand where your (6/9)^4 come from?

Comment: The python code correctly simulates the question yes

Comment: I'm using a geometrical argument.  The space, so to speak, of solutions occupies a four-dimensional hypercube of side $6$; the space of all combinations (whether they are solutions or not) occupies a four-dimensional hypercube of side $9$.  The ratio of volumes is $(6/9)^4$.  It may be easier to consider this situation with only two dimensions first.

Comment: @GarethMa: One does have to be a little careful to be sure that the solutions are "as dense as" the overall combinations, so that the hypervolumes are compared on an apples-to-apples basis.  Because each of the coordinates is only translated, and not scaled, this is OK.  But I admit I'm being pretty handwavy here. :-P

Comment: Is it somehow similar to how you can't say even number is "less dense" than the natural number set?

Comment: Also I am feeling a bit dumb now but can you explain a bit more for the (6/9)^4? Maybe help with 2/3d first

Comment: +1 great answer despite a bit of hand waving!  BTW i would love to see a picture of the feasible region for the $3$-segment version of this problem: in the 9x9x9 cube there would be a bunch of weird pieces which could be translated and affine-transformed and re-assembled into a 7x7x7 cube!

Comment: @GarethMa the same way the 4-segment version gives you a hypervolume that can be transformed into a 6x6x6x6 hypercube within the 9x9x9x9 hypercube.  I can draw the 2-d case, but not the 3-d case and certainly not the 4-d case.

Comment: I am sorry but can you show the 2-d case? Thank you :( I feel dumb

Comment: @antkam: Thanks for the kind words!

Comment: @GarethMa: I've edited to add a discussion of the two-dimensional case.

Comment: @BrianTung - The 3-segment, 6-pieces version of the problem gave me a good 10-15 mins of fun this morning while stuck in traffic.  :D  And you're right -- only translations needed, no need for e.g. affine transforms as I previously mentioned.  Now that I can visualize it, I wonder why there arent interesting toys (e.g. wooden puzzles) based on it.  I have never seen a cube cut into those 6 pieces in real life.

Comment: @GarethMa - ha!  of course someone else (in puzzling.SE) already wrote a [nice answer (with diagrams!)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17380) showing the 3-segment, 6-pieces cut.  in the context of your problem, imagine the cube is 7x7x7, and then you take those 6 triangular pyramids and spacing them out a little bit toward the corners of a 9x9x9 cube... kinda like the blue "river" between the two red triangles in brian's diagrams.  hard to visualize but that's what happened in brian's solution (for 3 segment case).

Comment: I have also thought of an alternative way, can you see if it's reasonable? So as you have mentioned, the x and y have a linear relationship without scaling (y=x+c). That means the "volume" of the set of solutions must be equal. Volume of y-solutions is 6^4(Each y has 0-6), region of consideration is 9^4. Therefore P=(6/9)^4?

Comment: @GarethMa: That is essentially what I'm saying, so I agree that it's correct, but I'm not sure why I see that it's an "alternative way."

Comment: ohohoh I'm sorry. I just couldn't visualise "sliding the pieces" in 4d lol, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I assume the $x_i$ are real numbers.  If they are integers, this is a simple counting exercise.

Let $D$ be the event that the $4$ intervals are disjoint.  Let $E$ be the event that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$.

- $P(D \cap E)$ can be evaluated with [a quadruple integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%5E-4+*+int+1+dw+dz+dy+dx%2C+x%3D0..6%2C+y%3D%281%2Bx%29..7%2C+z%3D%281%2By%29..8%2C+w%3D%281%2B+z%29..9):

$${1 \over 9^4} \int_0^6 d x_1 \int_{1+x_1}^7 d x_2 \int_{1+x_2}^8 d x_3 \int_{1+x_3}^9 d x_4 = {2 \over 243}$$

- $P(E) = 1/4! = 1/24$ via a combinatorial argument: any permutation is equally likely.
- From above you get $P(D \mid E) = P(D \cap E) / P(E) = {48 \over 243} = {16 \over 81}$.
- Finally you argue that $D$ and $E$ are independent and so $P(D \mid E) = P(D)$.

Comment: Quadruple integral??? I'm sorry but I'm *a bit* sure it's over-complicated. However I'll try.

Comment: Sorry I scared you with the quad integral!  :D  See the edited answer - it's quadruple but not bad at all.  It can certainly be done by hand with highschool calculus, but I used wolfram alpha instead.  Anyway, I love Brian's answer more than my own.